Problem observing the correctness of a Fourier transform property
I'm studying "Signals & Systems" by Oppenheim et al.

On page 391, for a real-valued $x[n]$ whose Fourier transform is $X(e^{j\omega})$:
$$x[n] \leftrightarrow X(e^{j\omega})$$
$$\mathcal{Ev}\{x[n]\} \leftrightarrow \mathcal{Re}\{X(e^{j\omega})\}.$$
Example 5.1 on page 362 for $|a|<1$:
$$a^n u[n] \leftrightarrow \frac{1}{1-ae^{-j\omega}}.$$
Example 5.2 on page 364 for $|a|<1$:
$$a^{|n|} \leftrightarrow \frac{1-a^2}{1-2a\cos(\omega)+a^2}.$$
It is easy to see that
$$a^{|n|}=2\mathcal{Ev}\{a^{n}u[n]\}.$$
Thus, I expect
$$2\mathcal{Re}\{\frac{1}{1-ae^{-j\omega}}\}=\frac{1-a^2}{1-2a\cos(\omega)+a^2}.$$
But my calculations show that this is not the case. I also tried to prove myself wrong by plotting these two expressions for a value of $a$, say $a=0.5$. But, WolframAlpha says I'm correct. See this link.

Could you please help me find the mistake. Thank you

Can you please define what exactly $\mathcal{Ev}$ is?  Specifically what happens at $n=0$ ? If it's defined as $x[n]+x[-n]$ your bullet #4 is wrong

$\mathcal{Ev}{x[n]}=\frac{x[n]+x[-n]}{2}$. Yes, you're just right. The problem lies in step 4. Unlike the continuous-time case, $u[n]=u[-n]=1$ for $n=0$.


It is easy to see that $a^{|n|}=2\mathcal{Ev}\{a^{n}u[n]\}.$

Nope. Assuming you defined the symmetry operator as $x[n] + x[-n]$, you will double up the sample at $x[0]$ so the correct version would be
$$a^{|n|}=2\mathcal{Ev}\{a^{n}u[n]\}-\delta[n].$$
where $\delta[n]$ is the Kronecker delta. Transforming is into the Frequency domain we get
$$2\mathcal{Re}\{\frac{1}{1-ae^{-j\omega}}\}=\frac{1-a^2}{1-2a\cos(\omega)+a^2} + 1.$$
which does indeed checks out fine.
